# Установка Linux на ноутбук hp

Tags: linux, fedora, hp

Подскажите, в чём проблема.
Был ноутбук HP 15-ba548ur. На нём без проблем работала fedora. Приобрёл ноутбук HP ProBook 645 G4 (3UN55EA). На нём без проблем работает предустановленная windows 10. Но linux установить не удаётся, любой дистрибутив.

При установке ubuntu ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При установке fedora ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И на этом зависает.
Иногда устанавливается, но при работе часто зависает, приходится перезагружать с кнопки питания.

Ставлю не рядом с windows, а только одну систему.

Comment: Что-то [связанное](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093882/unable-to-boot-after-installation-acpi-errors) с Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Какие дистрибутивы вы пробовали? В любом live-cd эти страшные крокозябры при загрузке?

Comment: Многие. Linux mint пока работает. Тестирую.

Comment: Ну здесь уже видна проблема кодировки. Советую попробовать другой дистрибутив, на не очень сильное железо стоит устанавливать xfce для более продуктивной работы. Ну это так к слову. Протестируйте другие iso)

Answer (score 1):

Форматирование диска, на который будет устанавливаться система, важно что бы не было русских букв в названии. Также стоит обратить внимание на устройство с которого вы загружаете систему - там тоже не должно быть русских символов.